# How do I fix the "failed to connect" error on android simulator from react native expo?

Tags: android, windows, react-native, expo, expo-go

On windows, when I run my expo/react-native project on an android simulator from android studio using the expo go app, it gives me a connection error:

"Uncaught Error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.96 (port 19000) from /10.0.2.16 (port42646) after 10000ms"

Most of the solutions available are for android devices not simulator but i currently don't have an android device
[Image of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b59do.png)